# Is a restrict type system in fsharp lang?

Tags: f#, type-systems

in f#
for operation "+" 
the function signature is

```
5+6 //int->int->int
```

but when I write code like the following , it is working

```
6.0 + 3.0 //float->float->float
```

in OCaml "+" is different with "+."

```
5 + 5 //int->int->int
5.0 +. 5.0 // float->float->float
```

it is more perfect and restrict rather than f#
why f# do this no-perfect type signature? 
and why f# do not support "+."?

so confused in the feature of f# :(

Comment: F# is not OCaml. :-) Functions/operators  can be overloaded and inlined, so they be applied to types that support that operation.  This is what you are seeing here. This is very helpful, because makes it easier and faster to write generic code. With some exceptions (like the above) F# is actually quite strict and doesn't do casts.

Comment: for generic code ,why not use generic type like haskell 
and the signature does not show any overloaded info
it should be more meaningful like Ord :: Num -> Num->Num

Comment: There are no type classes in F#. As it's not Haskell, nor OCaml. F#'s advantage is a simple and succint syntax, type inger

Comment: Type inferemce and the ability to leverage the .NET base class library. So you can mix and match FP with OO. In that sense it's objective is closer to Scala, rather than a pure FP lanfagm.m

Answer (score 5):

Unlike OCAML, F# allows for generic arithmetic through the use of a feature called Statically Resolved Type Parameters, which is similar to Haskell typeclasses.

The `+` operator can be used on any type that defines a `+` operation, and it is specialized to various .NET primitives as you can see in the code for `+` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs#L3373-L3394). This means that you can develop an arithmetic for custom types and have it "just work" without your own custom operators.

You can read about the history that led to this change in [The Early History of F#](https://fsharp.org/history/hopl-draft-3b.pdf), the second entitled "F# 1.0 – Improving the Functional Core: Overloaded Arithmetic".